# iOS Simulators in Xcode 6.4 showing multiple versions and have long "id" in the name

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have Xcode 6.4 installed and I also have Xcode 7 beta installed.  Recently I launched Xcode 6 and I showed multiple versions of the iOS simulators and they had long id/like uuid looking ids in the names.  Some of them do not work.  Has anyone seen this and does anyone have an idea of how to fix it.  I have deleted beta.  I have deleted and reinstalled Xcode 6 multiple times.  I have uninstalled Xcode 6 using an app like app cleaner as well.  I also have went and deleted via terminal the simulator at "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes ".  I tried sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all but I get command not found.

[image]

Comment: No solution, but I have the same issue after installing the beta.

Comment: Install Xcode 7 beta and Xcode 6.4 and you upgrade Xcode 7 beta, then you get the disorder.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can see them at this path: " **~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices** "

Try to delete all of them. then readd simulators from Devices window.

If you have more than one simulator of any device type with same version, Xcode behaves like this. For ex: three iPad 2 (iOS 8.4) simulator.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick.  I had looked in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes and deleted them but that did not work but yes I did find them in the dir you mentioned and deleted them and rebooted and emptied trash and then when I opened Xcode it was back to default simulators. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me - until the next reboot at which time they all came back with the UUIDs.

Answer (score 28):

Xcode -> Window -> Devices menu (cmd+shift+2)

There you can manage all your devices including simulators.

The IDs are displayed when there are more than one simulator for the same device and iOS version: delete the duplicate entries and it will show the iOS version instead.

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue quickly.  I had updated my XcodeColors project and reopened my own workspace when I saw this occur.

Answer (score 17):

you can also use the fantastic tool [snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot)

```
snapshot reset_simulators
```

is all you have to enter in your terminal and the simulators are rebuilt and clean afterwards.

Comment: I confirm. This is the best solution. I had like 50 simulators per devices and xcode 6 became unbearable since installing xcode 7. running snapshot took about 5 minutes but everything back to normal. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open this path " ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices " and remove all the devices in that path.

then open xcode-->windows -->devices-->
then remove all the duplicate devices then relaunch the xcode