# can't select proper iOS version for simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

After installing iOS 8.4 simulator for xCode 7.3 i get this strange behaviour. How can I fix it? There is no way to select the proper iOS version for simulator.
 [image: simulator list]

EDIT:
the fastest solution is to install [snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot)

- `sudo gem install snapshot`
- `snapshot reset_simulators`
  this will reset to your default simulators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode uses device versions for prevention of ambiguity which have same name. So if more than one device have same name and version number then it will show the device's `udid`. So, you should delete duplicate devices from Windows>Devices in Xcode. You can delete or rename your devices.

You can catch it from this path : **`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`**

You can refer [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316099/ios-simulators-in-xcode-6-4-showing-multiple-versions-and-have-long-id-in-the) or [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274517/simulator-name-is-shown-with-id-instead-of-os-name-in-xcode-6-2)